# Can't finish this block of code

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x

This is a tic-tac-toe game i'm trying to do. this is what i got till now..

```
def checkio(game_result):
try:
    for i in game_result:
        if game_result[0][0] == "X" and game_result[0][1] == "X" and game_result[0][2] == "X":
            return ("X")
        elif game_result[1][0] == "X" and game_result[1][1] == "X" and game_result[1][2] == "X": 
            return ("X")
        elif game_result[2][0] == "X" and game_result[2][1] == "X" and game_result[2][2] == "X":
            return ("X")
        elif game_result[0][0] == "X" and game_result[1][0] == "X" and game_result[2][0] == "X":
            return ("X")
        elif game_result[0][1] == "X" and game_result[1][1] == "X" and game_result[2][1] == "X":
            return ("X")
        elif game_result[0][2] == "X" and game_result[1][2] == "X" and game_result[2][2] == "X":
            return ("X")
        elif game_result[0][0] == "X" and game_result[1][1] == "X" and game_result[2][2] == "X":
            return ("X")
        elif game_result[0][2] == "X" and game_result[1][1] == "X" and game_result[2][0] == "X":
            return ("X")

    for i in game_result:
        if game_result[0][0] == "O" and game_result[0][1] == "O" and game_result[0][2] == "O":
            return ("O")
        elif game_result[1][0] == "O" and game_result[1][1] == "O" and game_result[1][2] == "O": 
            return ("O")
        elif game_result[2][0] == "O" and game_result[2][1] == "O" and game_result[2][2] == "O":
            return ("O")
        elif game_result[0][0] == "O" and game_result[1][0] == "O" and game_result[2][0] == "O":
            return ("O")
        elif game_result[0][1] == "O" and game_result[1][1] == "O" and game_result[2][1] == "O":
            return ("O")
        elif game_result[0][2] == "O" and game_result[1][2] == "O" and game_result[2][2] == "O":
            return ("O")
        elif game_result[0][0] == "O" and game_result[1][1] == "O" and game_result[2][2] == "O":
            return ("O")
        elif game_result[0][2] == "O" and game_result[1][1] == "O" and game_result[2][0] == "O":
            return ("O")

except:
    return ("D")
```

My problem is that "D", which needs to be returned if there's a draw, returns "null" instead. 
I know that my try-except statement is incorrect cause except only handles errors(is that right?).
I cant seem to find the right way to return "D" when the first block doesn't have any match.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there's no error, but nothing in `game_result` matches any of the `if` criteria. Try adding `else` statements to the end of all those `elif` blocks to return 'D'

Answer (score 0):

Try-except only works for exceptions (errors). Your problem is that since no exception is thrown, the except is never executed. What you need to do instead is return "D" at the end of the loops, where the function ends. If you return a value before the end of the function, the function will stop immediately. Just remove the try/except parts and stick the return ("d") at the end.

Here's an example:

```
if i == 6:
   return true
return false
```

In this case `return false` is only executed if i != 6.